# Postfix .NET Docker : How to send email through Postfix with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp, postfix-mta

I have my C# app. running into Docker, also I have installed Postfix in order to send emails from the app.

But I cannot send emails, I always got some errors:

> Failure sending mail.   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
>   message)

Here is my source code:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
//smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
//smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sysuser", "syspassword");
smtp.Host = "host.docker.internal";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply@mywebsite.com");
mail.To.Add("clubber.lang@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

smtp.Send(mail);
```

As you can see I use the "" address, from what I understand it is the real localhost  of my machine(my app is running into a docker container).

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Is postfix installed in the same docker container?  If not you need to change your `smtp.Host` to a different name, where the postfix is located.

Comment: Postfix is not installed on a container, but on the machine directly. It is why I try to reach the "real" (non dockerized) machine. But without success :-(

Comment: You might want to try calling the ip directly as your smtp host.  Your .net app is trying to do a dns lookup of 'host.docker.internal' and probably failing that.